# Label using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, label, three.js

I am using  a WebGL project to plot line across the globe. It is using three.js, the plotting is happening properly what I cannot figure out is how to label the points where the plot is starting from and ending to. If possible could some one help me with this? I would be really grateful if someone could help. The codes goes as below:

```
<script>
        var planetTilt = latlngDeg2rad(23.5);
        console.log(planetTilt);
        var planetRadius = 6378;
        var rotationSpeed = 0;
        var cloudsScale = 1.02;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var camera, controls, scene, renderer, geometry, meshPlanet, meshClouds;
        var clock = new THREE.Clock();
        var cameraZoomFactor = 6;
        var displayHelp = false;
        var curZoom = 100;
        var markerGeom;
        var markerMaterial;
        var stats;

        function onWindowResize(event) {
            width = window.innerWidth;
            height = window.innerHeight;

            renderer.setSize(width, height);

            camera.aspect = width / height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            controls.screen.width = width;
            controls.screen.height = height;

            camera.radius = (width + height) / 4;
        }

        function init() {
            if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                clearAlpha: 1,
                clearColor: 0x000000,
                antialias: true
            });
            renderer.setSize(width, height);
            renderer.sortObjects = true;
            renderer.autoClear = false;
            renderer.gammaInput = true;
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;

            renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            var container = document.getElementById('container');
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, width / height, 50, 1e7);
            camera.position.z = planetRadius * cameraZoomFactor;
            scene.add(camera);

            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.rotateSpeed = 0.3;
            controls.noZoom = true;
            controls.noPan = true;
            controls.staticMoving = false;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.4;

            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.right = '0px';

            document.body.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF);
            dirLight.position.set(1, 0, 1)
                .normalize();
            scene.add(dirLight);
            var camLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
            camera.add(camLight);

            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x999999);
            scene.add(ambientLight);

            var planet = new cpPlanet({
                planet_radius: planetRadius,
                planet_tilt_rad: planetTilt,
                planet_cloud_texture: "common/textures/cloud.png",
                planet_surface_texture: "common/textures/earth_surface.jpg",
                planet_normals_texture: "common/textures/earth_normals.jpg",
                planet_specular_texture: "common/textures/earth_specular.jpg",
                planet_geom_segments: 64,
                planet_geom_rings: 64,
                use_surface_shader: true,
                create_combined_mesh: false
            });

            meshPlanet = planet.surface_mesh;
            scene.add(meshPlanet);

            meshClouds = planet.cloud_mesh;
            scene.add(meshClouds);

            // markers and tracks
            var marker_radius = 32;
            var marker_color = 0xff0000;
            markerGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(marker_radius, 5, 5);
            markerMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                ambient: 0x030303,
                color: marker_color,
                specular: 0x990000,
                shininess: 80,
                shading: THREE.SmoothShading
            });

            // need to update a bunch of stuff when window size changes
            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            var delta = clock.getDelta();

            meshPlanet.rotation.y += rotationSpeed * rotationSpeed * delta;
            meshClouds.rotation.y += rotationSpeed * 1.25 * rotationSpeed * delta;

            controls.update();

            TWEEN.update();

            stats.update();

            renderer.clear();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        function addData(locs) {

            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * locs.length) - 1;
            var start_lat = locs[index].lat;
            var start_lng = locs[index].lng;

            var data_size = 1;
            var start = Math.floor(Math.random() * locs.length) - 1;
            if (start + data_size > locs.length) {
                start = locs.length - data_size - 1;
            }

            var hue = Math.random();

            var i;
            for (i = start; i < start + data_size; i++) {
                var obj = locs[i];
                if (i != index) {
                    addTrack(25.2697, 55.3095, 28.6667, 77.2167, planetRadius, hue+.5);//delhi
                    addMarker(28.6667, 77.2167, planetRadius);
                    addTrack(25.2697, 55.3095, 35.6833, 51.4167, planetRadius, hue+.5);//terhan
                    addMarker(35.6833, 51.4167, planetRadius);
                    addTrack(25.2697, 55.3095, 51.0000, 9.0000, planetRadius, hue+.5);//germany
                    addMarker(51.0000, 9.0000, planetRadius);
                    addTrack(25.2697, 55.3095, 33.6667, 73.1667, planetRadius, hue+.5);//Islamabad
                    addMarker(33.6667, 73.1667, planetRadius);
                    addTrack(25.2697, 55.3095, 31.2000, 121.5000, planetRadius, hue+.5);//Shanghai,
                    addMarker(31.2000, 121.5000, planetRadius);

                }
            }
        }

        function zoomToStart() {
            new TWEEN.Tween({
                scale: 1
            })
                .to({
                scale: 100
            }, 2500)
                .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut)
                .onUpdate(function () {
                var true_scale = this.scale / 100;
                meshPlanet.scale.set(true_scale, true_scale, true_scale);
                meshClouds.scale.set(true_scale * cloudsScale, true_scale * cloudsScale, true_scale * cloudsScale);
            })
                .start();
        }

        function addMarker(lat, lng, radius) {
            var marker_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(markerGeom, markerMaterial);
            var marker_position = latlngPosFromLatLng(lat, lng, radius);

            marker_mesh.position.x = marker_position.x;
            marker_mesh.position.y = marker_position.y;
            marker_mesh.position.z = marker_position.z;

            marker_mesh.name = "trackmarker";
            meshPlanet.add(marker_mesh);
        }

        function addTrackLine(spline, hue) {
            var num_control_points = 32;
            var i;
            var colors = [];
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            var pos;

            for (i = 0; i < num_control_points; i++) {
                var index = i / num_control_points;
                pos = spline.getPoint(index);

                colors[i] = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
                colors[i].setHSV(hue, (1.0 - i / num_control_points), 1.0);

                geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
            }
            pos = spline.getPoint(1.0);
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));

            geometry.colors = colors;

            var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff,
                opacity: 1,
                linewidth: 2
            });
            material.vertexColors = true;

            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
            line.name = "trackline";
            meshPlanet.add(line);
        }

        function addTrack(start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, radius, hue) {
            var num_control_points = 8;
            var max_altitude = 500 + Math.random() * 1200;

            var points = [];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < num_control_points + 1; i++) {
                var arc_angle = i * 180.0 / num_control_points;
                var arc_radius = radius + (Math.sin(latlngDeg2rad(arc_angle))) * max_altitude;
                var latlng = latlngInterPoint(start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, i / num_control_points);
                var pos = latlngPosFromLatLng(latlng.lat, latlng.lng, arc_radius);

                points.push(new THREE.Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
            }

            var spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3(points);

            addTrackLine(spline, hue);
        }








/*
        var deleteMe = [];

        function newDataCallback(node) {
            if (node instanceof THREE.Line && node.name == "trackline") {
                deleteMe.push(node);
            }
            if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh && node.name == "trackmarker") {
                deleteMe.push(node);
            }
        }

*/

        window.onload = function () {
            if (!Detector.webgl) {
                Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
                return;
            }

            init();

            var num_new_data_adds = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_new_data_adds; ++i) {
                addData(locations);
            }

            zoomToStart();

            animate();
        }
    </script>
```

The main functions are, the addData, addMarker, addTrack, addTrackline. Can some one help me plot the line with labels? I can't figure out how to label the starting and ending point of these lines.

The sample project can be seen here: http://callum.com/sandbox/webglex/connected_planet/

Comment: @Lain - FYI: Be careful when capitalizing not to include variables. In this case, changing `i` to `I` breaks the code.

Comment: @Leigh Ah sorry my bad:( Used control f to find them, was very careless of me. Won't make the mistake again sorry.

Comment: @Lain - Okay, that is what I figured happened :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating labels is a bit tricky in WebGL 3d scene. Basic idea is to use html and css (or 2dcanvas/svg, i prefer svg) for drawing labels. For example create a div with text. Than you should position it according to the scene objects. For this purpose you can either use projector and unproject positions of the objects in 3d world to your html 2d layer, then position labels in html/svg layer using top/left attributes. This approach will be rather slow with lots of labels. The other approach is using 3d transforms and described [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/100000stars/). Also you should apply some tricks to hide labels which are positioned behind scene objects.

Comment: Can Some pseudo codes be provided to explain the labeling process in detail.

Comment: look inside armsglobe/js/markers.js (http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/projects/armsglobe/?ModPagespeed=off). Try to debug it for better understanding.